# Django how to make createsuperuser checks for duplicate email adress

Tags: django, django-models

```
def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
    user = self.create_user(
        username, email, password=password
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.is_staff = True
    user.active = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

I have made a custom user model. When I call createsuperuser, if the username I entered is already in the database, it will prompt

```
'Error: That username is already taken.'
```

But if I entered a email address which already exists in the database, it will not prompt the email has been taken error. Instead, it let me pass through and gave me the following error after I entered the password:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users_customuser.email
```

Is there a way to make it also check the email address like the way it checks the username?

Answer (score 0):

```
def create_superuser(self, username, email, password=None):
    duplicate = self.filter(email=email)  # I'm assuming `self` is User.objects
    if len(duplicate) != 0:
        return "Duplicate email"  # Customize your error handling logic here
    user = self.create_user(
        username, email, password=password
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.is_staff = True
    user.active = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

The uniqueness is being enforced by a constraint set at the database (probably because `unique=True` in the models.py), so that's where the error is being raised and Django doesn't realize it until the transaction is attempted.

The email field doesn't necessarily *have* to be unique if you don't want it to be, though it is a common practice.

edit: Instead of a naive `email=email`, you could do something more robust (but completely optional) like this:

```
email_field = self.model.get_email_field_name()
duplicate = self.filter(**{email_field: email})
```

Comment: Hello, I have tried your code, and it seems that now it does not even show the error. If I call createsuperuser with a duplicate email address it will not be added to the database and does not even show the 'UNIQUE constraint failed' error.